# Magento : Calling SOAP API on Local Server Returning HTTP Bad Request

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v2, http-request

I created SOAP API on my magento website and it's working correctly on live server. But now I need to using those API in another server machine at local environment (local machine with IIS7) and for this I created copy of live website on that machine with live database and perform further stuff like change url etc...; At local Website (front-end/back-end both) working correctly. But when I run API's, those are not returning correct result to me. every time returning bad request error `"faultstring":"Bad Request","faultcode":"HTTP"}`.

> SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request in
>   D:\Projects\Php\Dev6\mobile_app\mobile_action.php:97 Stack trace: #0
>   [internal function]:
>   SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('catalogCategory...', Array) #2
>   D:\Projects\Php\Dev6\mobile_app\mobile_action.php(97):
>   SoapClient->catalogCategoryTree('f6a180fd37c28c7...') #3
>   {main}{"faultstring":"Bad Request","faultcode":"HTTP"}

Code of API file :

```
try 
{    
    $soapClient = new SoapClient("http://192.168.xx.xxx:8086/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/");
    $sessionId = $soapClient->login('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx00xxxxxxxx'); //-- $sessionId returning result means soap client created

    $data = $soapClient->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId);
    $result = array('Success' => 1, 'category_list' => $data);
    echo json_encode($result);
    return;
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    return $e;
}
```

Also, it's only occurred when I used SOAP Client function calling like `$soapClient->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId)` But if I directly access data using Mage instance then it's returning correct result. for example with following code API resulting correctly -

```
try 
{    
    $soapClient = new SoapClient("http://192.168.xx.xxx:8086/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/");
    $sessionId = $soapClient->login('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx00xxxxxxxx'); //-- $sessionId returning result means soap client created

    $arr = array();
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
    if (count($_categories) > 0) {
        foreach ($_categories as $_category) 
            {
              $current_catg_id = $_category->getId();
              $arr[] = array("catg_id" => $current_catg_id, "name" => $_category->getName());
           }
    }
    $result = array('Success' => 1, 'category_list' => $arr);
     echo json_encode($result);
    return;
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo $e;
    return;
}
```